# trying to keep the original value of a list python

Tags: python

ignore the code its working perfectly but the problem is when that i have the t list that i need it value for a procedure so what i did is i made a new empty list (aux) and put t values inside of it so the original list doesn't get changed but it still does for some reason this is the code

```
def listeDesTermes(k):
    Un = 0 
    t = [1,1]
    i=2
    while Un < k:
        Un = t[i-1] + t[i-2]
        t.append(Un)
        i=i+1
    return(t[0:len(t)-1])
#---------------
def Maximal (t) : 
    Maximal = 0
    for i in range(1,len(t)) :
        if t[i] > t[Maximal] :
            Maximal = i
    return(Maximal)
#--------------- 
def DecompsitionK(k,aux):
    s= 0
    Tdecomp = []
    while not k == s :
        maximum = Maximal (aux)
        if s + aux[maximum] <= k :
            s = s+aux[maximum]
            Tdecomp.append(aux[maximum])
            aux[maximum] = -69
        else : 
            aux[maximum] = -69
    return(Tdecomp)
#--------------- 
def conctenationT(t,Tused):
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] in Tused :
            t[i] = str(t[i])+"1"
        else:
            t[i] = str(t[i])+"0"
#---------------    
t=listeDesTermes(50)
# problem starts here 
aux = t
print(t)
Tused=(DecompsitionK(50,aux))
conctenationT(t,Tused)
print(t)
```

Comment: Where is this `new empty list (aux)`?

Comment: yup aux is the empty list

Comment: I don't see where you make a new list.

Comment: i typed       aux = t

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: `aux = t` does nothing except make a new variable named `aux`. No Copies Happen Here.

Comment: why tho aux supposed to get the value of t

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: `aux supposed to get the value of t` <= you're making things up now.

Comment: isnt the same for example :

Comment: b = 10  a = b so now a == 10 isnt the same ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but please consider taking a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements).

Comment: The same, but not a copy.

Comment: Ok, being confused is allowed here. Please read the link. Its simple. Variables are just named labels which have a reference to an object. Manipulating variables does not change objects. If you want a copy you have to be explicit, eg `aux = t[:]` or `aux = t.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

In python, variables are saved by reference and not by value. Therefore in order to create a copy of an immutable, in your particular case - a list, you must use the method of `list` - `copy()`, or the function `copy` from the module `copy`. (`copy.copy`, there is also `copy.deepcopy` which copies sub-lists as well).
You need to edit your code to:

```py
aux = t.copy()
```

And it should work!

Comment: i dont understand why tho

Comment: Because when you do this you don't work on the original list but on its copy so you don't modify the original one. Please try it out and tell me wether it works or not

Comment: it works so whats the original

Comment: The original is `t`, `aux` is a **copy** of t.

Comment: Please mark is as solved if it helped you